# Is it okay to say 'What's it like for them'?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Let's imagine I want to ask someone how do they feel about some situation or how do they live after something happened or even asking for opinion of some thing? Can I ask the question "*What is it like for them?*" or there are some better options to ask it?

In Russian we can ask something like 'Каково это для них?'.

Comment: I don't know Russian, so that bit doesn't help me understand exactly what you want to know how best to phrase. But note that ***What's it like** for you?* could often be distinguished from ***How do you feel / What are your feelings** about it?* The former is often a relatively informal alternative to more "clinical" queries such as *What is your [personal] **experience** of it?* - used perhaps by a news interviewer to put someone more at ease. But the ***feeling*** versions usually imply you're more interested in emotional reactions than the actual experiences undergone by the other person.

Comment: In short, ***what kind of reply*** is your question intended to elicit? Broadly, are you hoping the reply will focus more on ***facts**,* or on ***feelings**?* (Without that clarification, the question **Needs more detail**.)

Comment: Most users here do not know Russian. You should assume that all users only speak English, and ask questions using only English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine, though from the way you asked the question, it sounds more like you are asking someone directly, in which case:

> What is it like for you?

You could also say:

> How do you cope?
>
> How do you deal with it?